# Spring boot thin launcher exec jar is not located

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin

I have created a spring boot maven project and tried to convert it in to thin jar using plugin

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.25.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

It create a thin jar but when I tried to run it using

```
 java  -Dthin.root=. -Dthin.archive=. -jar target/thin-jar-poc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I am getting below error:

```
Cannot locate launcher: ./repository/org/springframework/boot/experimental/spring-boot-thin-launcher/1.0.25.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.25.BUILD-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.launch(ThinJarWrapper.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.main(ThinJarWrapper.java:107)
```

I am not able to figure out the reason.

Comment: Is it suitable for you to use maven-jar-plugin instead of spring boot plugin? It may be much easier to configure thin jar using  maven-jar-plugin and maven-dependency-plugin.

Comment: I would not be able to use the maven-jar-plugin and maven-dependency-plugin because I am trying to do the PoC on spring-boot-thin-layout

Comment: I faced the same issue. How did you solve it?

Comment: I copied the jars to target directory manually if I ran mvn:clean each time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that network was behind a proxy and it was not downloading the dependencies 
I put a settings.xml in {thin.repo}/.m2 directory with correct proxy settings and It worked